# Create multiple layers BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, layout

Do you know how to create a multiple layers BlackBerry applications
such as the Trapster, Poynt apps...

There will be a bottom layer displaying a map (users can interact with),
and upper layers containing buttons that user can click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways

1. use map field and add it with other controls on screen if you don't need to change data on map.
2. If you need to change data on map, like having markers override `paint` method. With some special cares.